How to make apt update just one repo?
Is there a way to run apt update for just one specific repo, without deleting all the conf files in /etc/apt/sources.d?
For context, I'm writing a Dockerfile based on an image which has a lot of sources enabled, and I just need to install one specific package. Updating all repos takes a long time, so I'd like to simply update the one repo I need.
I know I could delete the unneeded list files, but that seems more fragile as the upstream image changes in the future.

Answered here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/65245/apt-get-update-only-for-a-specific-repository

Also here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/27362/how-to-only-install-updates-from-a-specific-repository
